# jQuery reaching document.ready() despite .holdReady() call.  Slickgrid error - Slick is not defined (5 out of range 4) error - dependencies

Tags: jquery, slickgrid, undefined-behavior, undefined-reference, document-ready

In the following script utilizing jQuery and slickGrid, I keep getting an error saying `Slick is not defined (5 out of range 4)` or `Slick is not defined (6 out of range 4)` - Both in FireBug, and in Chrome I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Slick is not defined
$.ready.$.css.opacity
f.Callbacks.o jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
f.Callbacks.p.add jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
e.fn.e.ready jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
(anonymous function)
e.extend.globalEval jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
e.extend.globalEval jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:4
e.extend.each jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:4
f.fn.extend.append jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:3
f.fn.extend.html jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:4
e.extend.access jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
f.fn.extend.html jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:4
$.ajax.success AJAX.js:26
f.Callbacks.o jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:2
w jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d jquery-1.7.2.min.js.php:4
FBL.ns.handleStateChange
```

However, if I comment out `var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);`, the script runs fine.  I have confirmed all the scripts are loading, going so far as to fire alerts in each one.  Also in Firebug/Chrome, I read the loaded scripts, and they appear correct.  Is there anything I could be overlooking?  The page code is as follows:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.grid.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/surge.slickGrid.css" /> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.calendarPicker.css" />  
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" />

    <div style="position:relative; overflow:visible; margin:25px 0 0 0;">
        <div id="loader" style="position:absolute; z-index:997;top: 62px; left:200px;"><img src="images/loading.gif" border="0" /></div>

        <div id="dateInput" style="visibility:hidden;"><p><label for="datepicker">Date: </label><input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"/></p>

    </div>
        <div id="myGrid" style="width:900px;height:200px;visibility:hidden;"></div> 
    </div>

      <div class="options-panel">
        <h2>Instructions:</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Select the date by clicking the date image above the table</li>
          <li>Enter your event data (you can enter multiple events for that date)</li>
          <li>To add another event, hit your <em>TAB</em> key and a new row will be created</li>
          <li>When you're all done for this date, click the <em>Commit Changes</em> button to have your events saved to the site</li>
        </ul>

        <h2>Options:</h2>

<button>Commit Changes</button>
      </div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js.php"></script>
<script>
$.getScript("js/slickGrid/slick.grid.js");
    $.getScript("js/slickGrid/surge.core.js");
        $.getScript("js/slickGrid/surge.slickGrid.js"); 
            $.getScript("js/jquery.calendarPicker.js"); 
                $.getScript("js/jquery.json-2.3.min.js");   


</script>

<? //Instantiate   slickGrid jQueryUI widget ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Ready');
    //======== if I comment the following line out, the script completes without error =======
    var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);


    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "clip" );
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide loading image div and show loaded jQuery modules
   $('#loader').hide();
   $('#dateInput').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0},"slow");
   $('#myGrid').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0},"slow");

});
</script>   
    <hr />EOP
```

***Updated Script load sequence***

```
$.holdReady(true);
$.getScript("js/slickGrid/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js",function(){
    $.getScript("js/slickGrid/slick.core.js",function(){
        $.getScript("js/slickGrid/slick.grid.js",function(){
            $.getScript("js/slickGrid/surge.core.js",function(){
                $.getScript("js/slickGrid/surge.slickGrid.js",function(){
                    $.holdReady(false);
                    alert('Done Loading slicks'); 
                        var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
                        alert('After Grid created');
                        $('#myGrid').slickGrid({
                            forceFitColumns: true,
                            columns: [
                                { id: "venue", name: "Venue", field: "f_venue"},
                                { id: "eventName", name: "Event Name", field: "f_eventName" },
                                { id: "time", name: "Time", field: "f_time" },
                                { id: "pricing", name: "Pricing", field: "f_price" },
                                { id: "visible", name: "Visible", field: "f_visible", width: 20 }
                            ],
                            data: [
                              { f_venue: "Finn's", f_eventName: "Roy Rogers", f_time: "9pm", f_price: "$10 before 10", f_visible: 1 },
                            ]
                        });
                        alert('after data population');

                        var json = $.toJSON( $('#myGrid').slickGrid('data'));

                    }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  document.write('FAILED: '+exception); });
            }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  document.write('FAILED: '+exception); });
        }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  document.write('FAILED: '+exception); });
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  document.write('FAILED: '+exception) });//console.log( textstatus );
}).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  document.write('FAILED: '+exception) });//console.log( textstatus );
```

I am trying to load a series of .js files that are dependent on the script preceding it having successfully finished loading.  Thus, I'm using `.getScript()` (I am open to ANY other ideas, cause this is getting difficult to troubleshoot) to load the script, on success it loads the next or echos error to the screen, and this repeats until the last script, which should then display the grid and allow the `$(document).ready()` event to fire.  Problem is, neither of these things happen.  The `$.holdReady()` appears to do nothing, and while the alert('done loading slicks') fires properly, and web developer console reports no more errors, and scripts loading in the sequence I want, the grid isn't displaying, and the `$(document).ready()` event fires as though the `$.holdReady()` wasn't even there.  Any further insight into this implementation would help.  I know requireJS is built for exactly this (dependencies), but I really cannot figure out how to utilize it properly in this context.

***UPDATE - All Working Now Except `$.holdReady()`***

All working now except the `.holdReady()`.  I've made that a moot point by instantiating the grid at the center of the nest, so it only runs when all scripts have completed successfully.  Works good, and lighter weight than requireJS..  Although.`getScript()` will not cache and will ALWAYS reload the file from the server.  Could relace those calls with `$.ajax()` calls and enable caching for a pretty big performance increase on files you don't change often.

I'm posting the final nested script in case some people are having trouble getting slickGrid working for them (the documentation SUCKS for such a great product!).

```
<script>$.holdReady(true);</script>  
<script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/slickGrid/lib/firebugx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js.php"></script>
<script src="js/slickGrid/plugins/slick.cellrangedecorator.js"></script>
<script src="js/slickGrid/plugins/slick.cellrangeselector.js"></script>
<script src="js/slickGrid/plugins/slick.cellselectionmodel.js"></script>
<script src="js/slickGrid/slick.formatters.js"></script>
<script src="js/slickGrid/slick.editors.js"></script>

<script>

    $.getScript("js/slickGrid/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js",function(){
        $.getScript("js/slickGrid/slick.core.js",function(){
            $.getScript("js/slickGrid/slick.grid.js",function(){

                        $.holdReady(false);
                        var grid;

                        var columns = [
                        { id: "VisitDate", name: "VisitDate", field: "VisitDate", width: 120, cssClass: "cell-title", editor: Slick.Editors.Text },
                        { id: "VisitTime", name: "VisitTime", field: "VisitTime", width: 100, editor: Slick.Editors.Text },
                        { id: "PrimaryComplaint", name: "PrimaryComplaint", field: "PrimaryComplaint", width: 100, cssClass: "cell-right", editor: Slick.Editors.Text },
                        ];

                        var data = [
                            {
                            "VisitDate": "11/30/2009",
                            "VisitTime": "0117",
                            "PrimaryComplaint": "General malaise "
                            },
                            {
                            "VisitDate": "02/08/2010",
                            "VisitTime": "0930",
                            "PrimaryComplaint": "General malaise "
                            }
                        ];

                        var options = {
                        editable: true,
                        enableAddRow: true,
                        enableCellNavigation: true,
                        asyncEditorLoading: false,
                        forceFitColumns: true
                        };

                        // grid = new Slick.Grid($("#acs-work"), returnObj.source, columns, options);
                        //var $tabs = $('#tabset').tabs();
                        //var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected') + 1; // => 0[edit]
                        //var panelstr = "#panel" + selected;
                        //to load dynamic data
                        // PROTO: grid = new Slick.Grid($(panelstr), returnObj.source, columns, options); 
                        grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options); 



                            $('#loader').hide();
                           $('#dateInput').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0},"slow");
                           $('#myGrid').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0},"slow");

            }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  document.write('FAILED: '+exception); });
        }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  document.write('FAILED: '+exception) });//console.log( textstatus );
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  document.write('FAILED: '+exception) });//console.log( textstatus );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getScript` runs an ajax http request which is not guaranteed to resolve and run before the document is "ready". Therefore it is entirely likely (probable) that your `$(document).ready(function(){...});` code is getting run before those 5 `$.getScript` commands are completed.

I've never used `$.getScript`. Instead to make the site load faster just move all your javascript to the footer. That way the page will load before it fetches the javascript. This will have the same effect as using `$.getScript` in that the page will render before it loads the javascript, but its not doing it asynchronously.

`$.getScript` I would assume, is for when you want to fetch a script via ajax after a user action or something similar, rather than to make the page load faster (which is what I'm assuming you're using it for).

Comment: Thanks for your input Thomas.  I would need clarification on a couple things though.  This page is the center content of a site that uses static header and footer pages.  Adding to the footer would cascade to all of my other pages which really isn't something I want to do as these scripts are pretty data heavy.  Second, by placing it in the footer, do the scripts no longer load asynchronously?  The issue of them having to be loaded in order(or all completing their load before the grid object is created) is critical it seems.  I felt .holdReady() sounded perfect, but I can't get it to work...

Comment: By "add to the footer" what I mean is "place them as low down as you can". The more content before the scripts the better. If you can get some of the scripts into the footer then do that, otherwise don't worry about it. Presumably they're not going to be huge scripts. i.e. the size of jquery is only a few kb and having it in the header isn't a bad thing. Anyhow, the main point is I'm not altogether sure why you're trying to load script asyncronously... as I said `$.getScript` is only really for use when you're trying to get a script after a user action or something.

Comment: If you're just loading scripts the first time the page loads then there's no reason why you can't just put them into script tags in the HTML and load them normally. If they're huge files that take a long time to download then put them into the footer and have an `if` statement to not download them on other pages apart from that one.

Comment: when I do that, and view the NET log in FireBug, it shows the scripts all loading at the same time.  They do NOT load in the order they are listed like CSS files do.  I nested them as I need the first script to COMPLETE the load, then on the success function, load the next, when that one completes successfully, then load the next.  Normally all these scripts could be combined into one, and the code would complete sequentially.  However, different pages of mine use different modules, so it is broken up.

Comment: The reason I'm using `$.getScript()` is as follows:
$.getScript has an event handler that fires when a script has completed downloading successfully, I use that to start the next script download.  Lighter and no additional scripts to load (like RequireJS uses) to make functional dependencies.  There very well could be a better function to use ( $.ajax() comes to mind, and would allow me to cache), but I'm not aware of what one would be...  Plus, the $.getScript function is a part of the jQuery library, thus none of the other scripts will start loading until jQuery has completed successfully.

Comment: my implementation of getscript actually SLOWS the page load down some due to no caching, and forcing one .js file to complete before the next even begins downloading, it's done purely to resolved dependencies/order-of-operation issues

Comment: I'm saying DON'T USE $.getScript. Just load the scripts normally, as you would normally. This way they're sequential... and will load in the order the `<script>` tags are. This is a better way to do what you want. DON'T USE $.getScript you're using it in the wrong context.

Comment: please see 3 comments above.  My FireBug log shows all scripts loading at the same time.  Of course the jquery one is larger than the others, and finishes loading last.  When I had simple listed `<script>` tags, they were not loading sequentially.  That's why this issue came about in the first place.  Traditionally, I've always just listed script tags in order of dependency, and have rarely had an issue.  This is one of very few instances this has presented itself.  And I'm not the only person to have this issue (thus why requireJS even exists).

Comment: I do appreciate your help thomas, and have figured out a working solution based upon a documented JavaScript issue.  All jQuery/JavaScript resources I have found list this as a common problem for them, and to use requirejS or the method I integrated into my code above.  I was just having trouble getting it working.  Again, I do appreciate the time you've given me for help...

Comment: Glad you've got the answer. :)